# How to define a custom prompt in JShell from a script?

Tags: jshell

I am trying to create a custom JShell prompt and want to load it from a file directly.

But it is not showing the custom prompt when loading the set prompt from a file, but I am able to do it writing the same commands on JShell.

Ex:
I have a file 'jshell_prompt_file' contains these 3 lines to set the prompt:

```
/set mode genspice -quiet
/set prompt genspice "GetNetConnectivity > " "--------> "
/set feedback genspice
```

When I load the file while invoking  JShell, it does not change the prompt.

```
1:31am [login1] ~/JSHELL 1023:-)jshell jshell_prompt_file
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 13.0.2
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell>
```

But when I copy-paste the same command to set feedback, then it changes it

```
2:53am [login1] ~/JSHELL 1034:-)jshell jshell_prompt_file
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 13.0.2
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> /set feedback genspice

GetNetConnectivity >
```

Can someone help me to achieve this without the user have to type it on command prompt? I want the first prompt to be the custom prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feedback mode need to be set with a specific JShell command line option : `--feedback`.

In your file `jshell_prompt_file` keep only the first two lines:

```
/set mode genspice -quiet
/set prompt genspice "GetNetConnectivity > " "--------> "
```

and run JShell with:

```
jshell jshell_prompt_file --feedback genspice
```